# Change position of toggle switch in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, button, position, toggle

I have a toggle switch below and I'm trying to position it somewhere else on my page but for some reason it doesn't go past this tiny bubble of space. I added the 'top' and left' elements under .switch{ but as I increase the numbers, the button stays put. Does anyone know how to fix this? There are position elements in the other classes and whenever I change the numbers, the toggle switch and text gets all messed up. I want to be able to move the button in its entirety.

html:

```
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" id="togBtn">
<div class="slider round">
   <!--ADDED HTML -->
   <span class="on">ON</span>
   <span class="off">OFF</span>
   <!--END-->
</div>
</label>
```

css:

```
.switch {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 34px;
  top: 500;
  left: 600;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ca2222;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2ab934;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(55px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(55px);
  transform: translateX(55px);
}

.on
{
  display: none;
}

.on, .off
{
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

input:checked+ .slider .on
{display: block;}

input:checked + .slider .off
{display: none;}


.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;}
```

Comment: Position values need a unit. Pixels or something, not just a number unless the number is 0

Answer (score 1):

top & left value need unit eg. 500px, 50rem or 10% but why you added position :absolute in .switch class, if position required for your case then ok, but using absolute positioning the switch is not proper solution